# WooCommerce: How to set a default table-rate shipping method?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 2 shipping methods defined:

1. Table Rates - Priority 1
2. Local Pickup - Priority 2

Within Table Rates, I have 3 options:

1. Registered Australian Post (2 to 8 Business Days): $6.50
2. Tracking and Freight Insurance: $7.25
3. Nation-Wide Delivery (5 to 12 Business Days): $1.40

All orders that fall within the Local Table Rate area are presented with these 3 options and by default, Option 3 is selected ( I assume because it is the cheapest)

It defaults the priority to table rates but you can't define priority within the actual table rates. I want the default option to be Option 1: Registered Australian Post (2 to 8 Business Days)

I have discovered that the default shipping method is set here:

`WC()->session->[chosen_shipping_methods] => a:1:{i:0;s:17:"table_rate-5 : 70";}`

and apparently can be accessed and modified using the following two methods:

```
WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods');
WC()->session->set('chosen_shipping_methods', $chosen_method);
```

BUT, I can get the current `chosen_shipping_methods` I just can't set a new one.

I'm trying to set it using the action `woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen` but it's not working

Can anyone guide me to what I should be looking at?

Comment: do you have this online? so at least we could see?

Comment: yes, you can see at - https://www.janomesewingcentre.com.au/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using which worked as required:

```
/*=Use the shipping method filter to set the "selected" shipping method to 
 * the first (default) method in the list
**************************************************************************/
function oley_reset_default_shipping_method( $method, $available_methods ) {

    $method = key($available_methods);
    return $method;

}
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', 'oley_reset_default_shipping_method', 10, 2);
```

(NOTE: This worked because the shipping rate I wanted was actually the first in the list but just wasn't being selected by default)

Answer (score 1):

by only looking on your website and not looking at the code, I'm guessing this might be what you want...

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'reigel_chosen_shipping_methods' );

function reigel_chosen_shipping_methods(){
    remove_action(current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);
    WC()->session->set( 'chosen_shipping_methods', array('table_rate-7 : 72') );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In WooCommerce 3.0.7, this was the only way that I could make it work. WooCommerce seems to ignore all my attempts at using the "woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method" filter to change the default shipping method. Maybe due to other conflicting things in my code. I added another session variable to check if the shipping method in the session has already been changed once (to allow the customer to choose their preferred method without this being reverted every time the cart reloads).

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder shipping methods via the admin dashboard. Goto *Woocommerce > Shipping > Shipping Methods* and change the order using drag and drop.

[image]

Comment: That has absolutely no effect because it is unrelated. The shipping priority works - that is not the issue - the default rate selection is the problem

Comment: Table rates? Are you talking about a specific shipping addon then? If so, which one? Have you looked at their documentation?

Comment: this answer should be correct.. because the first method is always the default selection in the checkout..

Comment: The first answer is not correct.  WooCommerce sets a priority on the shipping methods as the answer describes BUT it does not set a 2nd level priority on the 3 shipping methods defined within Table Rates.  Table Rates has multiple options.  WooCommerce does not allow selection of a priority for these sub-options BUT instead, defaults to the cheapest option,

Comment: @php-b-grader I'm sorry but you should asked about Table Rates and not about WooCommerce. The two might be related, but who knows about how Table Rates implement their shipping priority... might be good for you to ask the plugin author.

Comment: I have asked the shipping author - they don't implement shipping priority - they use the default WooCommerce shipping priority, hence why I asked about WooCommerce. I am trying to change the default WooCommerce shipping priority. The admin screen does not allow for the granular selection that I need and neither does Table Rates hence why I am looking to change it programmatically and asking for programming assistance...

Comment: @php-b-grader Thanks for clarifying that it's for a _specific Woocommerce addon_. Has the plugin author confirmed they have no filters you can hook into programmatically?

Comment: Plugin author has confirmed they can't do it and they don't know how to programmatically hook into it because it's set and controlled by woocommerce,  not the plugin