# WooCommerce: Programmatically changing the default shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce cannot prioritise table rate shipping methods so I am trying to do it myself but am failing horribly.

I have tried to add an action at the point I think it is set but it is not working. Here is what I have tried (I just want to use the first shipping method in the available shipping methods array):

```
function reset_default_shipping_method() {

    $available_methods = WC()->shipping->packages[0]['rates'];
    $chosen_method = key($available_methods);
    WC()->session->set( 'chosen_shipping_methods', $chosen_method );

}
add_action('woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen', 'reset_default_shipping_method');
```

I have tested `$available_methods` and `$chosen_method` and both are presenting as expected (when run in page) BUT, once I add it to the action `woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen` it doesn't seem to be updating.

e.g. If I run this through a different hook:

```
function output_to_footer() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) :

        $current_method = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods');
        $available_methods = WC()->shipping->packages[0]['rates'];
        $chosen_method = key($available_methods);
        WC()->session->set( 'chosen_shipping_methods', $chosen_method );        

        print "\n".'-----'."\n";
        print_r($current_method);
        print "\n".'-----'."\n";
        print_r($available_methods);
        print "\n".'-----'."\n";
        print_r($chosen_method);
        print "\n".'-----'."\n";

    endif;
}
add_action('print_footer_messages', 'output_to_footer');
```

It looks like everything is doing what it should, but when I run it from the action : `woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen` it "appears" to do everything BUT the shipping radio is still set to the old shipping method?

```
-----
Array
(
    [0] => table_rate-5 : 70
)

-----
Array
(
    [table_rate-7 : 72] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
        (
            [id] => table_rate-7 : 72
            [label] => Registered Australian Post (2 to 8 Business Days)
            [cost] => 4.0909
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 0.40909
                )

            [method_id] => table_rate
        )

    [table_rate-8 : 90] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
        (
            [id] => table_rate-8 : 90
            [label] => Tracking and Freight Insurance
            [cost] => 20.055881818182
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 2.0055881818182
                )

            [method_id] => table_rate
        )

    [table_rate-5 : 70] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
        (
            [id] => table_rate-5 : 70
            [label] => Nation-Wide Delivery (5 to 12 Business Days)
            [cost] => 0
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                )

            [method_id] => table_rate
        )

    [local_pickup] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object
        (
            [id] => local_pickup
            [label] => Local Pickup
            [cost] => 0
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                )

            [method_id] => local_pickup
        )

)

-----
table_rate-7 : 72
-----
```

I have been working on this all day and don't feel any closer to a solution.  Hoping someone here can help out.

Comment: So you'd like "Table rate" to be the default shipping method always? Which version of WooCommerce are you using? Also a note to say that `woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method` is a filter hook and not an action hook. So use `add_filter` instead of `add_action` and return your default shipping method

Comment: Table Rate is the default shipping method already - I want Table Rate Option 1 to be the default though, not Table Rate option 3.

Comment: PS. I'm too much of a novice to understand the difference between add_filter and add_action so while I hear what you're saying, I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method` is a filter hook not an action hook. Try the following code

```
function reset_default_shipping_method( $method, $available_methods ) {

    // If the shipping method has been chosen don't do anything
    if ( ! empty( $method ) ) {
        return $method;
    }        

    // add code to set 'Table Rate' as the default shipping method 

    $method = 'table_rate-5';

    return $method;    
}

add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', 'reset_default_shipping_method', 10, 2);
```

P.S: I have hardcoded `table_rate-5` as the default method to give you the gist, so change it to the desired one. Ideally you need to write up code to see if the method you are wanting to set as default is available in `$available_methods` and then work accordingly.

Comment: I hardcoded as well to try and force it and it still wont update.

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297571/woocommerce-how-to-set-a-default-table-rate-shipping-method

Comment: I did this and the method isn't being changed

Comment: Ok, this does work. Problem is I (and the code herein) was referencing the action hook 'woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen'.  You provided code for the filter: 'woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method' - Once I changed the hook, it worked. Please update your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up using which worked as required:

```
/*=Use the shipping method filter to set the "selected" shipping method to 
 * the first (default) method in the list
**************************************************************************/
function oley_reset_default_shipping_method( $method, $available_methods ) {

    $method = key($available_methods);
    return $method;

}
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_chosen_method', 'oley_reset_default_shipping_method', 10, 2);
```

(NOTE: This worked because the shipping rate I wanted was actually the first in the list but just wasn't being selected by default)